# Which attributes should I add to extract Exif data of jpg in NiFi use ExtractImageMetadata?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying extrat exif data from jpg files in nifi use ExtractImageMetadata processor.

Which attributes should I add to extract Exif data of jpg in NiFi use ExtractImageMetadata?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsfMQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0I2J.png)

When I run that processor, only original images out.

I expect extracted Exif data